# magento2 show cart items in other page than cart in phtml php code

Tags: magento2, php, checkout, cart, phtml

I want to get items that added to checkout cart and show that/those in other page.

I have tried many different ways, but in Magento 2 im not been able to do it.

Can you help me out?

Thank you

Comment: Could you please provide more info? what page eaxctly? How did you tied to do it? Basically you just need to copy checkout cart layout to your pages layout.

Comment: I think it doesn't matter at which page because the code will be the same.
Anyway I have a phtml page (lets say site.com/buy) and what to show all the cart items that any user add products to cart to show here.
I have tried some codes that have seen here in stackoverflow but none of them seems to work.
I have tried to copy the cart layout but didn't worked.

Comment: See answer below. Let me know if you need some additional changes. You can also contact me via skype f0rman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the simpliest example

Folder structure:

[image]

1 *magento_root/app/code/Furman/NewChekout/etc/module.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Furman_NewChekout" setup_version="0.1.0">
    <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>

    </sequence>
</module>
```

2 *magento_root/app/code/Furman/NewChekout/registration.php*

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Furman_NewChekout',
    __DIR__
);
```

3 *magento_root/app/code/Furman/NewChekout/composer.json*

```
{
"name": "furman/newchekout",
"description": "",
"require": {
    "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",

    "magento/magento-composer-installer": "*"
},
"suggest": {

},
"type": "magento2-module",
"version": "0.1.0",
"license": [

],
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "registration.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "Furman\\NewChekout\\": ""
    }
},
"extra": {
    "map": [
        [
            "*",
            "Furman/NewChekout"
        ]
    ]
}
}
```

4 *magento_root/app/code/Furman/NewChekout/etc/frontend/routes.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
<router id="standard">
    <route id="newcheckout" frontName="newcheckout">
        <module name="Furman_NewChekout"/>
    </route>
</router>
</config>
```

5 *magento_root/app/code/Furman/NewChekout/Controller/Cart/Index.php*

```
<?php

namespace Furman\NewChekout\Controller\Cart;

class Index extends \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index
{

}
```

6 *magento_root/app/code/Furman/NewChekout/view/frontend/layout/newcheckout_cart_index.xml*

(all xml please copy from magento core file to your file: ./magento_root/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml or [from here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml) )

And here is the result:
[image]

You can also delete all blocks that you don't want to show, or set your own phtml in xml

Comment: Hello, I tried this but when I go to domain.com/cart/index I have error 404 not found. Also I changed "furman" to my theme vendor.

Comment: @AlgertZh What front name do you use? It's what you specified in routes.xml

Comment: I have used: newcheckout
and I also tried domain.com/newcheckout/index and I got the same thing

Comment: and also tried domain.com/newcheckout/cart/index

Comment: @AlgertZh try, domain.com/newcheckout/cart/index

Comment: see my answer below, I have also used that one

Comment: @AlgertZh also please take into account that usual root on magento consists of domain/frontname/controllername/actionname

Comment: I understand, and thats what I have done, but don't know why it doesn't work

Comment: @AlgertZh did you run - php bin/magento module:enable Vendorname_ModuleName? Then setup:upgrade and cache:flash after you created module?

Comment: I did the setup:upgrade and the cache:flush, but didn't do module:enable.
But did tried now and says Unknown module, tried to do module:enable --all and it says no module change.

When I do the setup:upgrade I can see the NewCheckout module in the list, so I think that part its ok

Comment: @AlgertZh f0rman is my skype login. Ping lets communicate closer. Because it's to long here

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Get all items:**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart'); 
$itemsCollection = $cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();
$items = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();
    if(count($items)) {
        foreach($items as $item) {
        echo 'ID: '.$item->getProductId().'<br />';
        echo 'Name: '.$item->getName().'<br />';
        echo 'Sku: '.$item->getSku().'<br />';
        echo 'Quantity: '.$item->getQty().'<br />';
        echo 'Price: '.$item->getPrice().'<br />';
        echo "<br />";            
    }   
}
```

**Get Visible items:**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart'); 
$itemsCollection = $cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();
$itemsVisible = $cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
    if(count($itemsVisible)) {
        foreach($itemsVisible as $item) {
        echo 'ID: '.$item->getProductId().'<br />';
        echo 'Name: '.$item->getName().'<br />';
        echo 'Sku: '.$item->getSku().'<br />';
        echo 'Quantity: '.$item->getQty().'<br />';
        echo 'Price: '.$item->getPrice().'<br />';
        echo "<br />";            
    }   
}
```

Comment: I tried both of them, and nothing is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the valid answer, only a thing.

In your **newcheckout_cart_index.xml** you don't need copy entire checkout_cart_index.xml. Only need to add an update handle layout task.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="checkout_cart_index"/>
</page>
```